# List representation in Template for Drools rule engine

Tags: java, drools

Ask is to have comma separated values in a template that would be consumed in the variable of list type in drools rule engine. Not able to achieve this using "Item1", "Item2" in a single row in template.
Need to know how list items can be represented in the drools template so the same can be consumed in the variable of list type.

Comment: Kindly share some code snippet, so that i can understand you problem statement better.

Comment: Template Class has variable - items (ArrayList)
Wherein the template (.xls) stores the items in a column header saying "Items" and one cell contains multiple values which are comma separated like this - "item1", "item2", "item3"...so on. We are not able to read the items arraylist in template class as multiple values. Instead these are being read as one single string like "item1, item2, item3". Drools version we are using 6.x.